# How to convert nested generic to another nested generic that inherits from the first one?

Tags: c#, generics

This code:

```
public interface IInter { }
public class Concrete : IInter { /*... body ...*/ }
var t = (List<IInter>)new List<Concrete>();
```

Yields this error:

`Cannot convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Concrete>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<IInter>'`

Why is it ? how do I overcome it ? my goal is this:

```
var t = new List<List<IInter>>()
{
    new List<ConcreteA>(){/* ... data ... */},
    new List<ConcreteB>(){/* ... data ... */},
    // ...
    new List<ConcreteX>(){/* ... data ... */},
};
```

#### Edit:

Thanks for all your help. Ahh, I kinda abstracted things, to make it easier to read... but my real problem is this:

```
public class SingletonFactory<T> where T : IToken
{
    private SingletonFactory() { }
    private static SingletonFactory<T> _instance = new SingletonFactory<T>();
    public static SingletonFactory<T> Instance { get { return _instance; } }

    public T Produce(int position) { return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), position); }
    public T Produce(int position, string token) { return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), position, token); }
}
```

And then:

```
var keywords = new Dictionary<string, SingletonFactory<IToken>>()
{
    { "abc", SingletonFactory<Abc>.Instance },
    { "xyz", SingletonFactory<Xyz>.Instance },
    { "123", SingletonFactory<Num>.Instance }
};
```

So I guess it's much more complicated...

I'm using c# 4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a covrariant interface for the methods you need to access from `SingletonFactory<T>`.  This will ensure that your type T is output type safe.

```
public interface IToken { }
public class Abc : IToken { }
public class Xyz : IToken { }
public class Num : IToken { }

public interface ISingletonFactory<out T> where T : IToken
{
    T Produce(int position);
    T Produce(int position, string token);
}

public class SingletonFactory<T> : ISingletonFactory<T> where T : IToken
{
    private SingletonFactory() { }
    private static SingletonFactory<T> _instance = new SingletonFactory<T>();
    public static SingletonFactory<T> Instance { get { return _instance; } }

    public T Produce(int position) { return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), position); }
    public T Produce(int position, string token) { return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), position, token); }
}

var keywords = new Dictionary<string, ISingletonFactory<IToken>>()
{
    { "abc", SingletonFactory<Abc>.Instance },
    { "xyz", SingletonFactory<Xyz>.Instance },
    { "123", SingletonFactory<Num>.Instance }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var res = new List<Concrete>().Cast<IInter>().ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

A `List<Concrete>` *is* not a `List<IInter>` although  `Concrete` implements `IInter`.

You can use:

```
List<IInter> t = ConcreteList.Cast<IInter>().ToList();
```

[**Covariance and Contravariance FAQ**](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

This is called *[covariance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_%28computer_science%29)* and C# supports covariance (and contravariance) on generic interfaces and not generic classes. This is the following works but your example does not:

```
IEnumerable<IInter> e = new List<Concrete>();
ICollection<IInter> c = new List<Concrete>();
```

Covariance is also supported on arrays:

```
IInter[] a = new Concrete[3];
```

Comment: Are you sure that we can write the first line? I did not know that and could not make it work. May it be `new List<IInter>` instead of `new List<Concrete>`

Comment: @MehmetAtaş: actually I was right the first time (damn you self doubt). Covariance for generic interfaces was added in .NET 4, so perhaps you are using an earlier version?

Comment: I did a little bit of tests and now I am clear. It works for FW >= 4.0 and does not work for FW < 4.0 (:

Comment: I use c# 4.0, is there a way to do it with Dictionary<> too (see my edit) ?

Comment: @Tal, `IDictionary<IFruit> fruits = new Dictionary<Banana>();`

Comment: There is no such thing `IDictionary<T>`, only `IDictionary<K,V>`, and it won't help in this case, because I can't use interface or abstract classes as the generic types due to the fact that I'm implementing singleton.. yea, it's tough riddle :-(

Answer (score 2):

Because you cannot assign a `List<ConcreteA>` to a `List<IInter>`, otherwise you could do this:

```
concreteAList = newList<ConcreteA>();
List<Inter> interList = concreteAList as List<Inter>;  // seems harmless
interList.Add(new ConcreteB());                        // not allowable
```

You *could* do:

```
var t = new List<List<IInter>>()
{
    new List<IInter>(){/* ... fill with ConcreteAs ... */},
    new List<IInter>(){/* ... fill with ConcreteBs ... */},
    // ...
    new List<IInter>(){/* ... fill with ConcreteXs ... */},
};
```

But I don't know if that accomplishes what you want.

Answer (score 1):

One way is:

```
IEnumerable<IInter> t = new List<Concrete>();
```

Another is:

```
List<IInter> t = new List<Concrete>().ConvertAll(x => (IInter) x);
```

Edit, adding better sample to show that it works (the test passes):

```
[Test]
public void CovarianceTest()
{
    var concrete = new Concrete();
    IEnumerable<IInter> t = new List<Concrete> { concrete };
    Assert.IsTrue(new[] { concrete }.SequenceEqual(t));

    List<IInter> t2 = new List<Concrete> { concrete }.ConvertAll(x => (IInter)x);
    Assert.IsTrue(new[] { concrete }.SequenceEqual(t2));
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that we can write the first line? I did not know that and could not make it work. May it be `new List<IInter>` instead of `new List<Concrete>`

Comment: @MehmetAtaş yes because `IEnumerable<T>` is covariant (you couldn't add a different type to the underlying list)

Comment: Ok, I tested too and now I am clear. It works for FW >= 4.0 and does not work for FW < 4.0 (:

Comment: The first method is great, but my real problem (sorry for not mentioning it first place - see my edit) is with Dictionary<>. The second would change my object's behavior.